# How to reuse SqlCommand parameter through every iteration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to implement a simple delete button for my database. The event method looks something like this:

```
private void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "delete users",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        command = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            User.connection.Open();
            command.Connection = User.connection;
            command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_Users WHERE userID = @id";
            int flag;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvUsers.SelectedRows)
            {
                int selectedIndex = row.Index;
                int rowUserID = int.Parse(dgvUsers[0,selectedIndex].Value.ToString());

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowUserID);
                flag = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (flag == 1) { MessageBox.Show("Success!"); }

                dgvUsers.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ConnectionState.Open.Equals(User.connection.State)) 
               User.connection.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

but I get this message:

> A variable @id has been declared. Variable names must be unique within
>   a query batch or stored procedure.

Is there any way to reuse this variable?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`Parameters.AddWithValue` adds a new Parameter to the command. Since you're doing that in a loop with the same name, you're getting the exception *"Variable names must be unique"*.

So you only need one parameter, add it before the loop and change only it's value in the loop.

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_Users WHERE userID = @id";
command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
int flag;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvUsers.SelectedRows)
{
    int selectedIndex = row.Index;
    int rowUserID = int.Parse(dgvUsers[0,selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
    command.Parameters["@id"].Value = rowUserID;
    // ...
}
```

Another way is to use [`command.Parameters.Clear();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first. Then you can also add the parameter(s) in the loop without creating the same parameter twice.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowUserID);
```

Use something like:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter p = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter();
```

Outside the foreach, and just set manually inside the loop:

```
p.ParameterName = "@ID";
p.Value = rowUserID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you are adding the same parameter again and again in each iteration of the loop.

I would move that code to a seperate method so that i can call it from multiple places as needed.

```
public bool DeleteUser(int userId)
{
    string connString = "your connectionstring";
    try
    {
      using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
      {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_Users WHERE userID = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userId);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      //Log the Error here for Debugging
      return false;
    }

}
```

Then call it like this

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvUsers.SelectedRows)
 {
   int selectedIndex = row.Index;
   if(dgvUsers[0,selectedIndex]!=null)
   {
     int rowUserID = int.Parse(dgvUsers[0,selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
     var result=DeleteUser(rowUserID)
   }
   else
   {
      //Not able to get the ID. Show error message to user
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
public static class DbExtensions
{
    public static void AddParameter(SQLiteCommand command, string name, DbType type, object value)
    {
        var param = new SQLiteParameter(name, type);
        param.Value = value;
        command.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
}
```

Then, call this:

```
DbExtensions.AddParameter(command, "@" + fieldOfSearch[i], DbType.String, value[i]);
```

Comment: this would always add a new parameter, while what you want is changing the existing one (see accepted answer)